# How to convert pictures to Open Office format (odt) using htlatex?

Tags: htlatex

I am trying to convert a non scientific content (text with pictures) into .odt format, the only one accepted by a site for writers to upload material.   The following command works nicely for the text, but the pictures do not have the proper dimensions after conversion. I have experimented different formats .jpg,  .png, .pdf, but no change. Is there a workaround?

I call the pictures in the LaTeX source by:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Pariah-Canyon1.jpg}
htlatex filename.tex "xhtml,ooffice" "oofice/! -cmozhtf" "-coo -cvalidate"
```

I am getting a warning below, but could not fid any way to eliminate it.

TeX4ht warning --- Cannot determine size of graphic in Pariah-Canyon1.jpg (no BoundingBox)

Comment: Does the problem persist if you use a fixed width?

Comment: Yes, the problems remains the same, even with a fixed width in the LaTeX code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach might be just to substitute the graphic files after the conversion with the original versions. After all, most likely some cleanup of the conversion result will be required, and editing figures is just one of them.

A while ago, some digging in the `htlatex` code revealed that all images are converted with some fixed ratio. A [bug report](http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?175) concerning this issue was left unanswered.